# Error: could not create List from JSON string: "Home & Living" at new List

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

> /scraper_engine/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
>       process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
>                                     ^
>
> Error: could not create List from JSON string: "Home & Living"
>       at new List (/scraper_engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/list.js:22:17)
>       at List (/scraper_engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/list.js:15:12)
>       at ModelConstructor.ModelBaseClass._initProperties (/scraper_engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model.js:336:28)
>       at ModelConstructor.ModelBaseClass (/scraper_engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model.js:55:8)
>       at ModelConstructor (/scraper_engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:184:22)
>       at ModelConstructor (/scraper_engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:184:22)
>       at new ModelConstructor (/scraper_engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:184:22)
>       at /scraper_engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1870:19
>       at /scraper_engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:391:17
>       at /scraper_engine/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:13

All of sudden I am experiencing problem with the script that I have been running from long... And I have not used any listing function here but it throws some wired error stating that

> it could not create List from JSON string

Does anyone have solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the `&` symbol out of that data (`Home & Living`).. you may have to manually remove it from your database.

Comment: I am processing lacks of products from long time I never experienced with the ampersand symbol before this.. But as you said, i tried removing & and running ....but still the problem persists...

Comment: Maybe this github issue is related: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues/148